# Merge two collections, in case of duplicate elements pick the one with the latest date

Tags: c#, linq

I've got two collections of objects that are of the form

```
class Point
{
    string name;
    DateTime date;
    int val;
}
```

Collections to merge are of different sizes (sometimes equal, sometimes not), occasionally they have entries that have the same `name`. I want to merge both collections into one and in case i have two entries with the same `name` i want to only keep the instance with the most recent `date`.

*I initially thought i'd do this in 30secs but i'm breaking my legs here for over 2h now. I came up with a manual solution but it's horribly inefficient and overly complex. Asking if someone knows a short & performant LINQ 1-2 liner for a problem like that.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__

Comment: ...or perhaps [UnionBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.unionby) is easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
firstPoints
  .Concat(secondPoints)
  .groupBy(point => point.Name)
  .Select(points => points.OrderBy(point => point.Date).Last());
```